# Duplicating a list to a list with pointers

Tags: go

I have simplified the problem incredibly to a small runnable example of my issue, shown below:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    main_list := []A{A{"1"}, A{"b"}, A{"3"}}
    second_list := make([]*A, 0)
    fmt.Println("FIRST LIST:")
    for _, x := range main_list {
        fmt.Println(x.Name)
        second_list = append(second_list, &x)
    }
    fmt.Println("SECOND LIST:")
    for _, x := range second_list {
        fmt.Println((*x).Name)
    }
}
```

Which provides:

```
FIRST LIST:
1
b
3
SECOND LIST:
3
3
3
```

The simple task is creating `main_list` with some dummy structs. The real issue is creating references (pointers) from the values in `main_list` into `second_list`. **I absolutely do not want copies of the structs**, only pointers/references to the `main_list` structs. The second for loop iterates through the newly populated `second_list` and shows only the last value from `main_list` (`3` in this example) three times.

I expect the issue arrises with the way I am using `&x` in the first loop. With the way I get all three values of `second_list` to all be the same struct instance; I am going to assume that I actually made a pointer to the for-loop's iterator (as if it were a reference?). So all the pointers in `second_list` will always be the last item referenced in the first loop.

**The question**: How could I make a pointer from what `x` was pointing to at that moment in the for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding the address of the same `x` in every call to `append`.

You could initialize a new `x` and copy the value:

```
for _, x := range main_list {
    x := x
    second_list = append(second_list, &x)
}
```

Or create a new `x` directly indexing the slice:

```
for i := range main_list {
    x := main_list[i]
    second_list = append(second_list, &x)
}
```

Or if you want the address of the original value in the slice, you can use:

```
for i := range main_list {
    second_list = append(second_list, &main_list[i])
}
```

Comment: The third option, creating a reference to the original, was what I needed. In my actual project, the main list contains members that change. The secondary lists need to be associated to those struct instances as they change.